# Block any program at specific paths from being started

Tags: windows

I want to block any program at a specific full-path name from being executed.

For example, if `D:\foo.exe` is in the blacklist, any program renamed and moved to that path will not run. If renamed or moved to something or somewhere else, then the program may run if other conditions allow (ACL, etc.).

Is there a solution that will work across all versions starting from Vista (NT 6.0)? Additionally, is there any solution specific to Windows 10? If so, what is the "minimum required" version (e.g. v1507)?

Comment: How about creating a placeholder `D:\foo.exe`? With ACL so it cannot be overwritten, removed, executed etc.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Good idea. That's not applicable in my case because the drive may be formatted, or other way that the ACL could be overridden programatically.

Comment: Is there some X behind this Y? (like in [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)). If the drive may be formatted or the executable may be renamed (and it's OK to run it then), then what's the point?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The actual case is that I'm going to perform some testing, and I repeatedly reset the testing area. For some other reasons, the path is fixed. I need the path to be blocked, but I'm in no need of blocking any specific program (files).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own anti-exec program.

There are various articles to be found on hooking process creation in the kernel,
but they all require installing a driver, which is not very portable and will
encounter driver signature problems on later Windows versions.

The simplest solution would be to write a small DLL to be injected into all
processes, which will, in the context of the process, get its path and
terminate it immediately if coming from this path.

Injecting the DLL is done using regedit and navigating to
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs`.
On later versions of Windows, `AppInit_DLLs` is disabled when Secure Boot is enabled.

See the Microsoft article
[Working with the AppInit_DLLs registry value](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/197571/working-with-the-appinit-dlls-registry-value).

A skeleton for such a DLL may look like:

```
BOOL
WINAPI
DllMain ( HINSTANCE hInst, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID) {
  TCHAR acModule[MAX_PATH];
  switch (dwReason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      GetModuleFileName(NULL,acModule,MAX_PATH);
      to_be_written(acModule);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```